# Conditionally apply one-time binding in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding

I came across a situation where I have a lot of items in my list and some of them are in their final state and wouldn't change and some are going to change. I was thinking, is there a way to use Angular's one time binding ('::') conditionally? Like if I have a final flag true - use one time binding, otherwise - regular binding.

Would I have to duplicate my entire DOM structure with ng-if and have one with one-time binding and the other with regular one?

Comment: conditional one time binding isn't something supported currently, and it's doubtful that you would gain any performance benefit from trying to force it through `ng-if` and duplicated code, unless you are talking about thousands of items, and at that point, why would you have that many items in the UI in the first place?

Comment: @Claies, I have a chat window and while there are much less than thousands messages at the same time, those messages have quite a few data dependant fields like sender, text, time of arrival and so on. And the latest sent message is pending confirmation from server that it was delivered. While all other messages can stay static, this one needs to change on conrimation event.

Comment: @Claies besides, you should always try to keep the number of watches to the minimum, while this component might have a reasonable amount of watches - the rest of the page where it is included might have a lot of watchers too or other taxing components. Just trying to be thrifty.

Comment: while I agree that avoiding *excess* watchers is definitely a solid practice, this isn't the approach that does that.  you are simply replacing the watch on an expression with a different watch on the `ng-if`, which marginalizes your gains.  Unless every `ng-if` covers many other watchers at once, it's not worth the extra debugging effort of duplicated UI elements.

Comment: @Claies "Unless every ng-if covers many other watchers at once" - yes, that is what I'm saying. Inside div covered by ng-if there's a big structure with multiple watches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most modular way is to declare custom directive that recompiles the DOM element from:

```
<div is-final='true' ng-model='myvar'></div>

<div is-final='false' ng-model='myvar'></div>
```

to:

```
<div>{{::myvar}}</div>

<div>{{myvar}}</div>
```

wrapping the if clause into the directive. This way you do not have to duplicate many LOC. The directive needs only to `require ngModel`, a `template`, `replace: true` and `link`. You can also avoid use template and `$compile` in `link`.

Comment: Yes, thank you morels, that is probably what I'm going to end up doing if this would be a situation that appears more that 2 times inside my app.

Comment: good approach dude. First time is simple coding, second time maybe need refactoring, from the third is a feature ;)

Comment: I'm having a bit of an issue wrapping my head around this solution. Can someone post a short snippet containing this directive?